# Cast MTLTexture from depth32Float to bgra8UNorm

Tags: metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I would like to process information from depth buffer using Metal Performance Shaders e.g. using gauss or sobel shaders.

I run into problems when using `MTLTexture` with `depth32Float` pixel format. `MPSImageGaussianBlur` or any other performance shader isn't accepting it as source texture.

I tried to convert it using: `depthBufferTexture.makeTextureView(pixelFormat: .bgra8Unorm)` but got error saying:

> validateArgumentsForTextureViewOnDevice:1406: failed assertion `source texture pixelFormat (MTLPixelFormatDepth32Float) not castable.`

Is there any way how to convert `depth32Float` to `bgra8UNorm` or any other pixel format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting from `depth32Float` to `bgra8UNorm`, in my opinion, does not make much sense, they have different dimensions and number of channels. In your case, the best solution would be using `MTLPixelFormatR32Float`.
To convert from `depth32Float` to `MTLPixelFormatR32Float` use `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! It's working for me. Actually it was my first idea but I was worried about performance issues. Thanks again

Comment: I'm glad I could help.